# Positioning of math in Tikz-Feynman

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, tikz-feynman, feynman

I'm trying to write an equation with a Feynman diagrams inside. My code is:

```
\begin{equation*}
   i\mathcal M_t= \feynmandiagram[inline=(d),vertical= b to d]{
        a[particle={$p_1$}] -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] c[particle={$p_3$}],
        b -- [photon] d,
        e[particle={$p_2$}]-- [fermion] d -- [fermion] g[particle={$p_4$}]
    };=\cdots
\end{equation*}
```

This positions the equation at the vertex `d`. However, I would like to write the equation between the vertices `b` and `d` (in the middle of the photon line). By removing the option `inline=(d)`, the equation becomes positioned below the graph (not what I want).

One way I managed to position the diagram correctly was by creating a new vertex between b and d and set the `inline` option to that vertex. (by doing `b -- [photon] k, k -- [photon] d,` This is not a desirable solution however, because the diagram becomes too big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made an invisible vertex k and invisible lines to this vertex. Here is the result:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
   i\mathcal M_t= \feynmandiagram[inline=(k),vertical= b to d]{
        a[particle={$p_1$}] -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] c[particle={$p_3$}],
        b -- [photon] d,
        b -- [opacity=0] k, k -- [opacity=0] d,
        e[particle={$p_2$}]-- [fermion] d -- [fermion] g[particle={$p_4$}];
    };=\cdots
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

If you wonder how these invisible lines look, you can change `opacity=0` to, say, `opacity=0.2`. This is how it looks:

[image]